# FormFacade not outputting form in blade L5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have in my composer.json

```
"illuminate/html": "^5.0"
```

I did a composer dump-autoload so all is well there.

In my app.config, I have in my providers section:

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

In my aliases section I have:

```
    'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

If I go to tinker and type Form::open(), predictably I get:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden">
```

However, in my blade page, if I do a:

```
        {!! Form::open() !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I see those words on the page!  I hate to ask such a stupid question but how can I get this to work within my blade page?

Comment: Did you save the file as `.blade.php` or just `.php`?

Comment: I have a master.blade.php and that then show.blade.php.  No matter which file I put the code in, it just shows up as the actual words and not a form.

Comment: You declared it wrong in your blade.

Answer (score 0):

When I put the Form tags on a blade page

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The source html source is

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/test" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="zgd8BaZDnnDeF6qFdODQM9tjwmBOWgQp1bAHqMWY">
</form>
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
   "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
}
```

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => [
   Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
 ],
'aliases' => [
   'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
   'Html' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
]
```

I have an alias for caching issues that I like to use

```
alias cleanslate='artisan cache:clear;artisan clear-compiled;composer dump-autoload;rm -fv ./storage/framework/views/*'
```

a combination of

```
artisan cache:clear;
artisan clear-compiled;
composer dump-autoload;
rm -fv ./storage/framework/views/*;
```

Which can help get rid of weird problems.

The only other thing I can think of is to run `composer update` and/or `composer install`

**Edit**

There are a few things you could try.

1. Make the storage directory writable.

   `chmod 777 -R ./storage`
2. Run a `diff` on the app directory of both project, the one that works and the one that doesn't and make any adjustments as needed.
3. Copy all of your source into the project that works.

Comment: Cleared it out but to no avail.  I'm still seeing the actual words in brackets on my page and in my source.

Comment: @ChrisFarrugia I updated my answer. I think something is weird in your configuration. If you get desperate you can try it on a new project and then do a diff of the two.

Comment: I really appreciate the thorough effort but none of that worked!  It is SO strange!  Edit:  In fact, if I just go to the welcome page and put those tags in, it STILL just shows the words for the tags and not the form itself!

Comment: I just went and created a new project and it worked on that project.  I literally copied and pasted the code from the config/app.php on the good project to mine and it still doesn't work!  How in the world coudl that be?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```